# Find smallest number in nested lists at the same index

Tags: python

I have a list of products:

```
list = [['product 1', 2.4, 322], ['product 2', 5.35, 124], ['product 3', 8.41, 521]]
```

How can I loop through the list to find the product with lowest number at the index [1]?

Answer (score 4):

You can use a `key` for `min`:

```
min(data, key=lambda p: p[1])
```

Comment: is there a way to use a loop and not min()?

Comment: @JSzum Of course but why would you want to do this? `min` is your most efficient solution.

Answer (score 0):

```
product = min(list, key=lambda item: item[1])[2]
```

Do not use `list` as a variable name, since `list` already refers to a list constructor.

Answer (score 0):

You can use an external variable. And if any value is less than that you simply replace the array.

```
data = [['product 1', 2.4, 322], ['product 2', 5.35, 124], ['product 3', 8.41, 521]]

min_arr = data[0]
for arr in data:
    min_arr = arr if arr[1] < min_arr[1] else min_arr

print(min_arr)

#Output
['product 1', 2.4, 322]
```